# ORM, C# and MySQL - Take2

Tags: c#, mysql, orm

This questions actually refers to [another one already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4464027/309308), now I want to reformulate it :)

My issue is: There is an online shop running on MySQL database, hosted somewehre on the internet. Now I'd like to do some administration stuff from my C# application.

What I want to do: All I want is to run SQL-queries on that database and get the results as entities in my application so I can browse through them like through normal Lists/Classes and then post back the changes to the database. The problem is not the connection to the database - it works fine (using SSH and Connector/NET driver) - but the question, how to turn the SQL-results into C# classes.

I had a closer look at [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) and [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/), but I still can't figure out which one suits best or - even worse - if these are really the right approaches to my problem.

So I don't want to build an application which stores its own data in a database but gets the data it needs from a public database.

I hope I could make myself more clear this time :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never really used ORM, but those links you posted look good and have made me want to learn. Why don't you read through the documentation for both and choose one to try out. From what you said i sounds like it is what you are after though.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is a very interesting topic :) But my point is, I think these solutions I posted rather aim at databased applications (which AFAIK is the real point of ORM). But I don't want to create those 150 entity-classes with tons of fields, I just want them to be automatically available as collections when I run a SQL-query.

Comment: @Quasdunk, Seems like what you want is for the ORM to generate the classes that you map so that you don't have to write them yourself. Is that right?

Comment: I posted an answer to your other question that pretty well answers this one as well.

Comment: @Mattias, exactly! And in reverse, I want the changes to be written back to the database!

Comment: @Quasdunk, I see. Then you should look at jvdbogae answer. That is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

ORM is definitely the way to, because it allows you to abstract your data access.

You may find a code generator helpful (to avoid the repetitive task of writing the classes and all their properties): [NHibernate Code Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703254/nhibernate-code-generation).

This way you can still use classic NHibernae instead of Fluent Hibernate, which by the way looks pretty useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I guess I will have to stick to NHibernate... Thank you guys! - AFK, reading documentations :-P